# Codimension 1 closed subspace as a kernel of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

My non-linear analysis book says that if I have a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ with close range $R$ and $\operatorname{codim}(R)=1$ (and also $\dim(\ker(T))=1$) then there exists $\phi\in Y^{*}$ such that 
$R=\{ y\in Y:\phi(y)=0\}$.

I suspect Hahn-Banach involved but I don't know why it is true. Could someone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: No need for Hahn-Banach. If $V \subset Y$ is closed and has codimension $1$, what does that imply about $Y/V$?

Comment: I can decompose Y to V and Y/V as direct sum  but where the functional comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the codimension of $R$ is one, the quotient space $Y/R$ has dimension one.
(For quotients of Banach spaces, see [this earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319867/166535), for example.)
Since $Y/R$ has dimension one, there is a linear isomorphism $f:Y/R\to\mathbb R$ (assuming you are working over the reals).
The quotient map $p:Y\to Y/R$ is linear and continuous and its kernel is $R$.
Now you can set $\phi=f\circ p:Y\to\mathbb R$.
Can you show that $\phi$ is continuous and find its kernel?