# A non trivial counterexample in three-space property

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

We know that completeness is a three-space property: Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a normed space $X$. Then, $X$ is complete if and only if $M$ and $X/M$ are complete.

I am looking for a non trivial counterexample: $X$ incomplete normed space but $X/M$ ($\neq \{M\}$) complete space with $M$ closed subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ be any incomplete normed space and $Y$ be any complete normed space.  Let $X=M\oplus Y$ (with, say, the norm $\|(m,y)\|=\|m\|+\|y\|$).  Then $M$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and the quotient $X/M\cong Y$ is complete, but $X$ is not complete because $M$ is not.

Comment: Dear Sir,Why M is closed subspace of X?

Comment: If $(m,y)\not\in M$ then $y\neq 0$ so its distance from any element of $M$ is at least $\|y\|>0$.