# Show that $V/W$ is a Banach space when $V$ is a Banach space and $W$ is a closed linear subspace.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

A similar question and partially complete proof have been posted here: [How to show that quotient space $X/Y$ is complete when $X$ is Banach space, and $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319867/how-to-show-that-quotient-space-x-y-is-complete-when-x-is-banach-space-and), and in fact my question comes from this post.

Let $V$ be a normed space and $W\subset V$ be a linear subspace. I have proved the following:

> **Lemma 1:** The followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $V$ is a Banach space;
> 2. For every sequence $\{x_{k}\}\subset V$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|x_{k}\|<\infty$ the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{k}$ is convergent, i.e. there exists $y\in V$ such that $$y=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}S_{M}\ \ \ \ S_{M}:=\sum_{k=1}^{M}x_{k}.$$

Basically, it shows that $V$ is a Banach space $\iff$ absolutely convergence implying convergence. And following the post above, I want to use this lemma, to prove the following statement:

> If $V$ is a Banach space and $W$ is closed, then $(V/W, \|\ \cdot\ \|_{V/W})$ is a Banach space, where $$\|[x]\|_{V/W}:=\inf_{y\in W}\|x-y\|_{V},\ \ \text{and}\ \ [x]\ \ \text{is the equivalence class}.$$

---

I have proved the most of it:

Let $([x_{n}])_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $V/W$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|[x_{n}]\|_{V/W}<\infty$.  We want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[x_{n}]$ converges to some $[x]\in V/W$, and then Lemma 1 concludes the proof.

Recall the definition of the quotient norm, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, we have $\|[x_{n}]\|_{V/W}=\inf\{\|x_{n}-y\|_{V}, y\in W\}.$ It then follows from the definition of infimum that, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$,  there exists $y_{n}\in W$ so that $$\|x_{n}-y_{n}\|_{V}\leq \|[x_{n}]\|_{V/W}+\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}.$$

It then follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_{n}-y_{n}\|_{V}<\infty.$

But $(x_{n}-y_{n})$ is a sequence in $V$ and $V$ is a Banach space, by Lemma 1, we know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}-y_{n}$ converges to some $x\in V$.

---

But then how could I conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[x_{n}]$ converges to $[x]$ in $V/W$? I tried to evaluate $$\Bigg\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[x_{n}]-[x]\Bigg\|_{V/W}=\inf_{y\in W}\Bigg\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n}-x)-y\Bigg\|_{V}$$ But I don't know how to use the above result.

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done:

Recall that $|| z+W ||_{V/W} \leq ||z|| $ for all $z \in V$ (i prefer to use the notation $z+W$ for the coset), thus

$$||\Big (\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-y_k) -x \Big) +W  ||_{V/W} \leq || \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-y_k)-x||_V \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.$$
Notice that the LHS is equal to
$$ ||     \Big(\sum_{k=1}^n  x_k  -x +W \Big)  -  \Big (\sum_{k=1}^n  y_k +W \Big )||_{V/W}  = ||  \sum_{k=1}^n  x_k    -  x +W ||_{V/W}, \  \text { since } \ \sum_{k=1}^n y_k \in W .$$
So, $ \sum_{k=1}^n x_k +W  \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} x$+W.

Comment: Do you mean since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{k}\in W$ instead of $\in V$? so that the coset $\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{k}+V$ is actually zero?

Comment: I got confused with the spaces, see my updated answer. Since $y_k \in W$, we have that $y_1 + \dots +y_n \in W$ and thus $ \sum_{k=1}^n y_k +W = [0]$.

Comment: No problem. The notation is quite confusing. Nice answer!