# How is taking closure reflected in the quotient for Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $F: V \to W$ is a continous linear map of Banach spaces, then $\ker(F)$ is closed and $V/\ker(F)$ is again a Banach space ([c.f. this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319867/how-to-show-that-quotient-space-x-y-is-complete-when-x-is-banach-space-and)).
As far as I understand it, the image of $F$ is not necessarily a Banach space, but only if the image of $F$ is closed.

I was wondering -- how can we ''algebraify'' taking the closure of $\mathrm{Im}(F)$, i.e.

1. if there's a way to get a ''natural'' Banach space structure on $\overline{\mathrm{Im}(F)}$; and
2. how would this induced structure relate to the Banach space $V/\ker(f)$ (so in some sense if there's an ''infinitesimal Banach-thickening of $V/\ker(F)$" that would be isomorphic to $\overline{\mathrm{Im}(F)}$ as a Banach space.)

(Sidenote: I don't know any functional analysis, so this might very well be a very naive/bad-behaved question)

Comment: What do you mean by "$F$ is closed"? I think that what you really want to say is "the image of $F$ is closed".

Comment: yeah that's what I meant, sorry. I'll fix it rn.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about the image of a Banach space via a discontinuous linear map?

Comment: I'm sorry but why does it need to be discontinous?
I was under the impression that the image of a continous map of Banach spaces is not necessarily again a Banach space, but only if it's closed in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the spaces $\ell_1 $ and $ c_0$ and the map $$F:\ell_1 \to c_0 $$
$$F(x) = x $$ then of course $$||F(x)||_{c_0}\leq ||x||_{\ell_1}$$
hence $F$ is continous linear mapping.
The closure of image $\overline{\mbox{im}F}=c_0$ hence it is dense subset of $c_0 $ and $\mbox{ker} F =0.$
So $\ell_1/\mbox{ker} F \equiv \ell_1$ and can not be made a "thicker" to be isomorphic to $c_0.$

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Heavy use of terminology from category theory**

From a category theoretic point of view, it would be better to distinguish the **range** $F(V)$ and the **image** which is defined as the kernel of the cokernel. In the category of Banach spaces as objects and continuous linear maps as morphisms, the kernel is indeed the null space $N=\{x\in V: F(x)=0\}$ with the restriction of the norm of $V$, the cokernel is the quotient $W/\overline{F(V)}$ with the quotient norm from $W$ and the image is $\overline{F(V)}$ with the norm from $W$. Finally, $V/N$ is the coimage of $F$. The *canonical map* between the coimage and the image is as well a monomorphism as an epimorphism of the category but it is not an isomorphisms. In Grothendieck's terminology, the category of Banach spaces is thus not an *abelian category*.